# VBA Runtime error 1004 range of object_global failed

Tags: excel, vba, global

If the cell has a value not equal to 0 then it will add up, X = X +1 so then I can see how many pages I need to print. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but here is what I have so far.
All help is needed! This is just a side project for work, so time is not an issue. I am creating this in excel also.

```
    Sub Find_Pages_to_Print()

    Sheets("Invoice").Select

    Dim X As Integer
    If Not Range("D9").Value = 0 Then
    X = X + 1



    If Not Range("D41").Value = 0 Then
    X = X + 1


       If Not Range("D70").Value = 0 Then
        X = X + 1


            If Not Range("D100").Value = 0 Then
            X = X + 1
            Else:
            X = X + 0



                If Not Range("D131").Value = 0 Then
                X = X + 1


                    If Not Range("D161").Value = 0 Then
                    X = X + 1


                        If Not Range("191").Value = 0 Then
                        X = X + 1
                        Else:
                        X = X + 0



                            If Not Range("D221").Value = 0 Then
                            X = X + 1


                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

MsgBox "Sets to Print: " & X
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at line:

`If Not Range("191").Value = 0 Then`

you probably want

`If Not Range("D191").Value = 0 Then`

Comment: I did not even notice that I had misspelled code, thank you for noticing that as I have been trying everything to get it right!